How to identify duplicate dictionaries and merge its sub list into one dictionary
I have a list with duplicate dictionaries based on the "id" key. I want to merge the sublist in the dictionary and create 1 dictionary out of the 2.
Ive tried a few things but my python skills are a bit rusty
[
  {
   "id": "1"
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key":"1"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1"
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key":"2"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "2"
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key":"3"
     }
   ]
  }
]

Final result should be this:
[
  {
   "id": "1"
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key":"1",
     },
     {
       "key":"2"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "2"
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key":"3"
     }
   ]
  }
]


itertools.groupby() might help you.

One way to do this is, you create a dictionary merged_data where the keys are the "id" values from your original list. You then iterate over each dictionary in the original list and either add the "sublist" items to an existing entry in merged_data (if the "id" is already there) or create a new entry (if the "id" is not present). Finally, you convert the merged dictionary back to a list.
Here is an example implementation:
merged_data = {}

# iterate through your original list (called data here) and merge dictionaries with the same id
for item in data:
    item_id = item["id"]
    if item_id in merged_data:
        merged_data[item_id]["sublist"].extend(item["sublist"])
    else:
        merged_data[item_id] = item

# convert the merged dictionary back to a list
result = list(merged_data.values())

print(result)


dict = [{
   "id": "1",
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key": "1"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1",
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key": "2"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "2",
   "sublist": [
     {
       "key": "3"
     }
   ]
  }
]
id_list = {}
new_dict = []
for index, element_dict in enumerate(dict):
    id = element_dict['id']
    if id in id_list:
        new_dict[id_list[id]]['sublist'] += element_dict['sublist']
    else:
        id_list[id] = index
        new_dict.append(element_dict)
print(new_dict)

The id_list will keep track of the sublists of past and we will add to id_list for new elements if old add to them

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
